# Submit form free when from errors in VueJs

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm currently building a form in Vue and I'm having a hard time submitting the form when the form is free from error messages.

I'm currently fixed so that the errors show when they should but the goal is to change the page after pressing the submit button.

I would appreciate any tip that could help me :)

HTML

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="submitMessage">
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="user-name">Name*</label>
      <input id="user-name" name="user-name" type="text" v-model="userName" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="age">Age</label>
      <input id="age" name="age" type="number" v-model="userAge" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="email">Email*</label>
      <input id="email" name="email" type="email" v-model="email" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="referrer">How did you hear about us?</label>
      <select id="referrer" name="referrer" v-model="referrer">
        <option value="google">Google</option>
        <option value="wom">Word of mouth</option>
        <option value="newspaper">Social Media</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
      <label for="message">Message*</label>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="50" id="message" name="message" v-model="message">Aa</textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button id="send" @click="sendForm()">Send Message</button>
    </div>
    <div class="errors">
      <p v-if="errors.length > 0">
        <b>Please correct the following error(s):</b>
        <ul>
          <li v-for="error in errors">{{ error }}</li>
        </ul>
      </p>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

Vue

```
<script>

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      userName: '',
      userAge: null,
      referrer: 'google',
      email: '',
      message: '',
      errors: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    submitMessage(e) {
      this.userName = '';
      this.userAge = null;
      this.email = '';
      this.referrer = 'google';
      this.message = ''
    },
    sendForm() {
      this.errors = [];
      if (!this.userName) {
        this.errors.push('Name is required');
      }
      if (!this.email) {
        this.errors.push('Email is required');
      } else if (!this.validEmail(this.email)) {
        this.errors.push('Valid email required.');
      }
      if (!this.message) {
        this.errors.push('Message is required');
      }
      if (!this.errors.length) {
        return true;
      }
      if (this.errors.any()) {
        this.$router.push('/thankyou');
      }
    },
    validEmail: function (email) {
      var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
      return re.test(email);
    }
  }
}

</script>
```

Router.js

```
import {
    createRouter,
    createWebHistory
} from 'vue-router';


import HomeBeerSearch from './pages/beers/HomeBeerSearch.vue';
import BeerList from './pages/beers/BeerList.vue';
import CustomerSupport from './pages/contact/CustomerSupport.vue';
import ThankYou from './pages/contact/ThankYou.vue'

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [{
            path: '/',
            component: HomeBeerSearch
        },
        {
            path: '/beers',
            component: BeerList
        },
        {
            path: '/support',
            component: CustomerSupport
        },
        {
            path: '/thankyou',
            component: ThankYou
        }
    ]
});

export default router
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the page by Vue router on SPA:

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'route name' })
```

or you can use raw JavaScript for external links:

```
window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

Comment: Thanks for your tip! How can I make the navigation work just when the form is error-free?

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // there is no such function errors.any()
    if (this.errors.any()) {
        this.$router.push('/thankyou');
    }
```

Your doing the navigation correctly but I think that the if statment logic is a little flawed. Try this instead:

```js
    // check if there are errors; if not go to the thank you page
    if (!this.errors.length) {
         this.$router.push('/thankyou');
    }
```